# Android get String Resource Id from value

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Is it possible to get the String Resource Id specified in strings.xml from the String value ?

```
    <string name="text1">Dummy Text</string>
```

I know how to get Resource Id (text1) from the String value (Dummy Text), but I want to get Resource Id (text1) from String value(Dummy Text) ? Here is how I get Dummy Text: But I want to get text1(Resource Id) from the Dummy Text value?

```
    context.resources.getIdentifier("text1","string",BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It doesn't really make sense right now :)

Comment: you can use String methods. substring() and indexof()

Comment: I think my question is clearer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the following function that uses reflection:

```
fun getStringResourceName(stringToSearch: String): String? {
     val fields: Array<Field> = R.string::class.java.fields
     for (field in fields) {
         val id = field.getInt(field)
         val str = resources.getString(id)
         if (str == stringToSearch) {
             return field.name
         }
    }
    return null
}
```

so by invoking `getStringResourceName("Dummy Text")` the function should return "text1".

The function can be even changed a bit to return the resource id corresponding to "Dummy Text":

```
fun getStringResourceId(stringToSearch: String): Int {
    val fields: Array<Field> = R.string::class.java.fields
    for (field in fields) {
        val id = field.getInt(field)
        val str = resources.getString(id)
        if (str == stringToSearch) {
            return id
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

so in this case by calling `getStringResourceId("Dummy Text")` you can get something like `2131886277` (the latter number is just an example).